# Not Centering Properly

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to center content under a certain area on a web page but when I translate it the content automatically centers to the top of the webpage.
I want to center the pricing stuff and the information stuff

HTML

```
 

  <div id="home" class="hero">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark fixed-top">
      <div  id="container" class="container">
        <p class="navbar-brand" style=" color:  black; font-family: Balsamiq Sans, cursive;"><strong> <img src="media/img/Logos/Nexus Development Logo.png" class="logo">LUNAR ANTIVIRUS | 月面</strong></p>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link" style="color: black;font-family: monospace;" href="./index.html"><strong>Home</strong>
                <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" style="color:  black; font-family: monospace;" href="#pricing"><strong>Pricing</strong></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" style="color:  black; font-family: monospace;" href="#info"><strong>Info</strong></a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <section class="HeroBanner">
    <h1 class="heroh1">LUNAR ANTIVIRUS | 月面<span class="herospan">- One Goal, One Passion. Lunar. -</span></h1>
      
    
    <section id="arrow-section-one" class="down-arrow">
      <a href="#Make-Arrow-Go-To-the-next-section-after-being-clicked"><span></span>Scroll</a>
    </section>
  </div>
</section>
  





<div id="info" class="nfcontainer">
<h1 class="nf">Lunar Information</h1>
<p class="nfp">Lunar Antivirus is used world wide by 1.97 million users.</p>
</div>


















  <div class="pricingContainer">
    <h1 id="pricing" class="pricing">Lunar Pricing</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sit nihil suscipit, iure doloribus neque ipsum amet aliquam facilis officia quas, doloremque nobis illo rem illum, dolorem facere eveniet laborum nostrum.</p>
    <!-- NOT MY CODE -->
  <div class="services">
    <section class="pricecol">
    <div class="icon">
    <i class="icon-magic"></i>
    </div>
    <h3><Span>Free Trial</span></h3>
    <ul  class="Pricing-Chart">
    <li  class="Pricing-Chart">3 Months Free Access</li>
    <li  class="Pricing-Chart">1 Device Connection</li>
    <li  class="Pricing-Chart">Limited Features</li>
    <li  class="Pricing-Chart">Free T-Shirt</li>
    </ul>
    <p>
    <a class="button"><span>FREE!</span></a>
    </p>
    </section>
    
    <section class="pricecol">
    <div class="icon">
    <i class="icon-leaf"></i>
    </div>
    <h3><Span>Individual</span></h3>
    <ul  class="Pricing-Chart">
    <li  class="Pricing-Chart">3 Device Connections</li>
    <li  class="Pricing-Chart">Mobile Access</li>
    <li  class="Pricing-Chart">Full Access to Premium Features</li>
    <li  class="Pricing-Chart">$25 Store Credit</li>
    </ul>
    <p>
    <a class="button"><span>9.99/month</span></a>
    </p>
    </section>
    
    <section class="pricecol">
    <div class="icon">
    <i class="icon-link"></i>
    </div>
    <h3><Span>Business</span></h3>
    <ul class="Pricing-Chart">
    <li  class="Pricing-Chart">Unlimited Device Connections</li>
    <li  class="Pricing-Chart">Mobile Access</li>
    <li  class="Pricing-Chart">Access to Professional Features</li>
    <li  class="Pricing-Chart">$50 Store Credit</li>
    </ul>
    <p>
    <a class="button"><span>24.99/month</span></a>
    </p>
    </section>
    </div>
  </div>
   <a href="#" id="toTopBtn" class="cd-top text-replace js-cd-top cd-top--is-visible cd-top--fade-out" data-abc="true"></a>
  <footer>
    <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-info" role="button"></a> Copyright @Damian Bennett 2022. All Rights Reserved <a href="#" class="btn btn-info" role="button"></a></p><p></p>
<p><a href="./tos.html" class="btn btn-info" role="button"> Terms Of Service</a>  <a href="https://discord.gg/" class="btn btn-primary" role="button"> Discord </a> </p>

</footer>


<script src="js/index.js"></script>
  </html>
```

CSS

```
body {
  /* background-color: #8EC5FC;
  background-image: linear-gradient(62deg, #8EC5FC 0%, #E0C3FC 100%);
 */
 background-color: black;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  height: 100vh;
  font-family: "Balsamiq Sans", cursive;
 
}


a:hover {
color: white;
text-decoration: none;
}
a:link {
 color:  black;
}
a:visited {
  border: 2px solid black;
  color: white;
}
a:hover, a:active {
background-color: white;
color: white;
text-decoration: none;
}

.btn {
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
  border: white;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  border: white;
}
  footer {
    position: bottom;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    clear: both;
  }


 
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.hero {
    height: 100vh;
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255,175,189,.7), rgba(100,216,243,.7), rgba(234,236,198,.7), rgba(245,146,176,.7), rgba(52,219,216,.7)) 0 0 / 1000% no-repeat, url(../media/img/wp/lunar\ antivirus.jpg) 0 0 / cover no-repeat;
    -webkit-animation: gradientAnimation 40s ease infinite;
    animation: gradientAnimation 40s ease infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes gradientAnimation {
    0%   { background-position: 0% 30%, 0 0;}
    50%  { background-position: 100% 70%, 0 0;}
    100% { background-position: 0% 30%, 0 0;}
}
@keyframes gradientAnimation {
    0%   { background-position: 0% 30%, 0 0;}
    50%  { background-position: 100% 70%, 0 0;}
    100% { background-position: 0% 30%, 0 0;}
}
.heroh1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    color: black;
  text-shadow:1px 1px 10px white, 1px 1px 5px white;
    font : normal 600 72px/1 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.heroh1 .herospan {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 1em;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: 300;
}

.logo {
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  padding: 10px; 
}


.pricingContainer {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display:inline-block;
  
}


.nfcontainer {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display:inline-block;
}
.pricing {
color: white;
}

.nfcontainer{
  color: white;
  left: 50%;
}

/* NOT MY CODE */
.services
{
width:1000px;
overflow:auto;
margin:0 auto;
}
.pricecol
{
width:31%;
background:rgb(38, 48, 52);
min-height:30%;
border-radius:10px;
position:relative;
padding:30px 0px;
text-align:center;
font-family:verdana;
float:left;
margin-left:20px;
}
.icon
{
width:60px;
height:60px;
border-radius:100%;
background:black;
color:#fff;
text-align:center;
position:relative;
margin:0 auto;

}
.icon i
{
font-size:30px;
position:relative;
top:15px;
}
h3
{
text-align:center;
background:rgb(34, 43, 47);
text-align:center;
border-top:1px solid rgb(25, 31, 34);
border-bottom:1px solid rgb(51, 60, 64);
color:#fff;
}
h3 span
{
border-top:1px solid rgb(51, 60, 64);
border-bottom:1px solid  rgb(25, 31, 34);
display:block;
padding: 10px 0px;
font-family:verdana;
font-size:20px;
}
.button
{
border-radius:34px;
border:5px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.07);
color:white;
font-size:16px;
margin-top:15px;
text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
cursor:pointer;
display:inline-block;
}
.button span
{
display:inline-block;
padding:10px 15px;
background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% black;
border-radius:20px;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) inset, 0px 2px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 

0.1) inset;
}
ul.Pricing-Chart
{
list-style-type:none;
padding:0px;
color:#fff;
font-family:verdana;
font-size:14px;
margin:0 auto;
text-align:center;
width:70%;
color:rgb(165, 174, 178);
border-bottom:1px solid rgb(51, 60, 64);
border-top:1px solid rgb(25, 31, 34);
}
li.Pricing-Chart
{
padding:10px 0px;
border-top:1px solid rgb(51, 60, 64);
border-bottom:1px solid rgb(25, 31, 34);
}
```

Like for example i want the pricing chart centered in the pricing section and i want the title and description centered but padded so it has space before the chart

and the information section I want the title and text centered but when i try to do it none of it stays in the black it jumps to the top of the webpage

any advice?

Comment: .nfcontainer, .pricing {
    text-align: center;
} add this in your css and check

Answer (score 0):

The CSS isnt all too pretty, but I guess

```
.pricing{  
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
color: white;
}
```